# truncate text in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a blog made by django. I want django to be able to read my post content and after django reaches to a specific word which I have already specified for Django, truncate the content.

for example this is a post content :

*Once upon a time, there lived a shepherd boy who was bored watching his flock of sheep on the hill. To amuse himself, he shouted, “Wolf! Wolf! The sheep are being chased by the wolf!” The villagers came running to help the boy and save the sheep. They found nothing and the boy just laughed looking at their angry faces.

**[django_Truncate]**

“Don’t cry ‘wolf’ when there’s no wolf boy!”, they said angrily and left. The boy just laughed at them.
After a while, he got bored and cried ‘wolf!’ again, fooling the villagers a second time. The angry villagers warned the boy a second time and left. The boy continued watching the flock. After a while, he saw a real wolf and cried loudly, “Wolf! Please help! The wolf is chasing the sheep. Help!”*

I want django to read it and when it reaches to [django_Truncate], truncate it.
so, the paragraph before [django_Truncate] will be displayed and the remainder will not be displayed.

is something like this possible?

Comment: You are looking for this template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html

Comment: @Hisham___Pak  no , I have already read it , 'truncatewords_html' will truncate by word count. I didn't say anything about word count or charachter count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) which takes the value and splits it on your desired string.

If you don't need to change the value to split on you can create it like this:

```
def split_on_string(value):
    return value.split("[django_Truncate")[0]
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
{{ mytext|split_on_string }}
```

If you want the string to split on to be a dynamic value you can adapt this function to take an argument, as is explained at the linked page. The page also explains where to create the custom filter and how to make it usable in a template.